# R Coding: Creating a complex conditional summary

Tags: r

I have a (cut-down) table containing the following pieces of information relating to a credit application process:

1. Date of Application
2. Email Address

The table can contain the same email address multiple times but with a different application date (it can be assumed that the same person has applied multiple times).

I would like to add a third column that tells me how many other applications have been seen with the same email address in the 90 days prior to application date.

How would I do this in R? Creating a summary by email address would be straightforward but adding the 90 day condition is for me the tricky part.

Coming from SAS I'd sort the table by email address and then use a lag function but any help with R would be massively helpful.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example to add clarity for those that would like to help. See the SO recommendations: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example would have been pretty helpful here but here's my best shot without it. What you're asking for could be done many ways. The easiest programming way is probably using a for loop over the rows of the data.

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(124)
emails <- 'None'
dates <- ymd('1900/01/01')
n_email = 500
for(i in seq_len(n_email)) {
  n <- rpois(1, 3) + 1
  d <- sample(seq(ymd('2018/01/01'), ymd('2019/09/01'), by = 'day'), n)
  emails <- c(emails, rep(as.character(i), n))
  dates <- c(dates, d)
}
dat <- data.table(emails, dates)
dat <- dat[order(emails, dates)]
dat[,counts := 0][]
#>       emails      dates counts
#>    1:      1 2018-06-16      0
#>    2:      1 2019-02-15      0
#>    3:     10 2018-09-08      0
#>    4:     10 2018-09-26      0
#>    5:     10 2019-02-05      0
#>   ---                         
#> 1942:     99 2018-07-03      0
#> 1943:     99 2018-07-07      0
#> 1944:     99 2019-02-07      0
#> 1945:     99 2019-04-09      0
#> 1946:   None 1900-01-01      0

for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  diffs = difftime(dat[i,dates], dat[emails == dat[i,emails],dates], units = 'days')
  count = sum(diffs < 90 & diffs > 0)
  dat[i, counts := count]
}
dat[]
#>       emails      dates counts
#>    1:      1 2018-06-16      0
#>    2:      1 2019-02-15      0
#>    3:     10 2018-09-08      0
#>    4:     10 2018-09-26      1
#>    5:     10 2019-02-05      0
#>   ---                         
#> 1942:     99 2018-07-03      1
#> 1943:     99 2018-07-07      2
#> 1944:     99 2019-02-07      0
#> 1945:     99 2019-04-09      1
#> 1946:   None 1900-01-01      0
dat[emails %in% dat[counts > 3,emails]][order(emails, dates)]
#>     emails      dates counts
#>  1:    396 2018-05-27      0
#>  2:    396 2018-07-10      1
#>  3:    396 2018-10-02      1
#>  4:    396 2019-02-13      0
#>  5:    396 2019-04-21      1
#>  6:    396 2019-04-22      2
#>  7:    396 2019-04-27      3
#>  8:    396 2019-05-02      4
#>  9:    396 2019-06-13      4
#> 10:    496 2018-03-06      0
#> 11:    496 2019-01-31      0
#> 12:    496 2019-04-08      1
#> 13:    496 2019-06-10      1
#> 14:    496 2019-06-24      2
#> 15:    496 2019-07-11      2
#> 16:    496 2019-07-23      3
#> 17:    496 2019-08-25      4
#> 18:     56 2018-11-16      0
#> 19:     56 2019-02-27      0
#> 20:     56 2019-04-09      1
#> 21:     56 2019-04-13      2
#> 22:     56 2019-04-25      3
#> 23:     56 2019-05-13      4
#>     emails      dates counts
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, here's a more concise, efficient way to do it as well making more use of data.table's capabilities. Note that this way doesn't require pre-sort

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(124)
emails <- 'None'
dates <- ymd('1900/01/01')
n_email = 500
for(i in seq_len(n_email)) {
  n <- rpois(1, 3) + 1
  d <- sample(seq(ymd('2018/01/01'), ymd('2019/09/01'), by = 'day'), n)
  emails <- c(emails, rep(as.character(i), n))
  dates <- c(dates, d)
}
dat <- data.table(emails, dates)
dat <- dat[sample(seq_len(nrow(dat)))]
dat
#>       emails      dates
#>    1:     70 2018-12-21
#>    2:    416 2018-10-02
#>    3:    289 2018-12-14
#>    4:     87 2018-03-02
#>    5:    441 2018-12-08
#>   ---                  
#> 1942:    365 2018-01-25
#> 1943:    200 2019-02-02
#> 1944:     14 2019-03-20
#> 1945:    166 2018-06-20
#> 1946:    161 2018-02-07
dat[order(dates), 
    counts := sapply(1:.N, FUN = function(i) {
        if(i == 1) return(0)
        x = c(0, diff(dates))
        days = 0
        place = i
        ret = 0
        while(days < 90 & place > 1) {
          if(x[place] + days < 90) ret = ret + 1
          days = days + x[place]
          place = place - 1
        }
        ret
      }),
    emails][order(emails, dates)]
#>       emails      dates counts
#>    1:      1 2018-06-16      0
#>    2:      1 2019-02-15      0
#>    3:     10 2018-09-08      0
#>    4:     10 2018-09-26      1
#>    5:     10 2019-02-05      0
#>   ---                         
#> 1942:     99 2018-07-03      1
#> 1943:     99 2018-07-07      2
#> 1944:     99 2019-02-07      0
#> 1945:     99 2019-04-09      1
#> 1946:   None 1900-01-01      0

dat[emails %in% dat[counts > 3,emails]][order(emails, dates)]
#>     emails      dates counts
#>  1:    396 2018-05-27      0
#>  2:    396 2018-07-10      1
#>  3:    396 2018-10-02      1
#>  4:    396 2019-02-13      0
#>  5:    396 2019-04-21      1
#>  6:    396 2019-04-22      2
#>  7:    396 2019-04-27      3
#>  8:    396 2019-05-02      4
#>  9:    396 2019-06-13      4
#> 10:    496 2018-03-06      0
#> 11:    496 2019-01-31      0
#> 12:    496 2019-04-08      1
#> 13:    496 2019-06-10      1
#> 14:    496 2019-06-24      2
#> 15:    496 2019-07-11      2
#> 16:    496 2019-07-23      3
#> 17:    496 2019-08-25      4
#> 18:     56 2018-11-16      0
#> 19:     56 2019-02-27      0
#> 20:     56 2019-04-09      1
#> 21:     56 2019-04-13      2
#> 22:     56 2019-04-25      3
#> 23:     56 2019-05-13      4
#>     emails      dates counts
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>